# List connected via SSH users

Tags: ssh, users, ps

I checked this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/431034/getting-list-of-opened-ssh-connections-by-name) and this [option](https://superuser.com/questions/248389/list-open-ssh-tunnels) - it is good, but it requires `sudo` rights. 
I need that this command may be performed by any user, for this reason I am using next command

```
ps -ef | grep sshd: | grep -v grep
```

and getting following result:

```
[owner@localhost ~]$ ps -ef | grep sshd: | grep -v grep
root      3175  2217  0 15:09 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [accepted] //Here just oppened putyy from windows pc
sshd      3177  3175  0 15:09 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [net]      //same as above
root      8062  2217  0 12:34 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/8 
root     24241  2217  0 13:37 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/10
root     31515  2217  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00 sshd: owner [priv] //non-root user connected
503      31567 31515  0 14:38 ?        00:00:00 sshd: owner@pts/12 //the same as above line
```

How to filter out only real connections?
What are the meaning of keywords "`priv`", "`accepted`", "`net`"?

P.S. I need to do it without `sudo` rights.

Comment: see also those commands: who, pinky, finger, netstat and their options. Also, check user:jherran answer for: w. Happy Mapped Show with Snow :p.

Answer (score 5):

Check command `w`:

> w  displays information about the users currently on the machine, and their processes.  The header shows, in this order, the current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system  load  averages  for  the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.
>
> The  following entries are displayed for each user: login name, the tty name, the remote host, login time, idle time, JCPU, PCPU, and the command line of their current process.
>
> The JCPU time is the time used by all processes attached to the tty.  It does not include past background jobs, but does  include currently running background jobs.
>
> The PCPU time is the time used by the current process, named in the "what" field.

Comment: and how to filter only `ssh` connected users?

Comment: You could do `w | grep -v localhost`. This command does not show localhost connections, so, all displayed are from outside.

Comment: and it's equivalent that all rest are `ssh` connections?

Comment: Note that w only lists users that are logged in through a tty. It is still possible to have users connected, running scripts, skipping the tty. ps will then show something like  `:  sshd: user@notty `, and this will not show up in w. To make this sort of ssh connection, use something like `# ssh -t '/bin/bash -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done' -t user@1.2.3.4`.